# ScriptBlock command not working with a variable

Tags: powershell

I am working with a Powershell script to invoke a command remotely to another server.

I tried to put the command in a variable to make it easier to configure but seems like the ScriptBlock with the variable is not being sent to the remote server, the other one works perfectly.

The script i am testing looks like these:

```
$remote_server="192.168.126.207"
$username="username"
$password="password"
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String $password
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$username",$pw
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remote_server -Credential $cred
$command = New-Item C:\Test.txt
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {$command}
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {New-Item C:\TEst2.txt}
```

And this is the Output:
[image: Script Output error]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Best Regards,

EDIT: After trying the options granted by Theo:

[image]

EDIT: After modifiying the path to the actual folder:
[image]

Switched the command to hostname to make it easier to understand:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside a scriptblock, a variable defined **outside** that scriptblock is unknown so you need [scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#scope-modifiers) like

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {$using:command}
```

You can also feed the $command variable to the scriptblock as parameter:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { param($cmd) $cmd } -ArgumentList $command
```

Comment: Hello Theo, many thanks for the fast reply, tried both options but still not working. Edited the question to add the Output and such.

Comment: @FrankPardo Choose a different path for the file, because you obviously do not have permissions to create files on the 'C:\' drive. I would also recommend adding the ItemType to the New-Item cmdlet: `New-Item -Path 'C:\Test.txt' -ItemType File`

Comment: The fact is that only the non-variable scriptblock is creating the file in the remote server, That's why the first one outputs the permission error and the second one does not, both are creating the file in C:.

I tried creating the file in the actual path and the first 2 options create it in the script folder in my pc and the last one creates it in the Remote PC Documents folder

Comment: I modified the command to "hostname" to make it easier to understand the issue, see image in the post at the end.